# Form Control Update Value doesn't update in ngOnInit()

Tags: angular

I'm creating dynamic forms from JSON in `ngOnInit()`

What I want to do is set some form controls manually, at the end of `ngOnInit()`.

```
ngOnInit(){
  ...Form creation...
  this.parsedJson.sections[0].form.controls['clientName'].setValue("John");
}
```

It doesn't update controls that way, how ever if I trigger the same action manually (ex: Button click), it will do the update.
`this.parsedJson.sections[0].form.controls['clientName'].setValue("John");`

I've also tried using `patchValue` instead of `setValue`, but the result is the same.

Form Creation:

```
for(let section of this.parsedJson2.sections){
  section.form  = new FormGroup({});
  if(section.section_type == 'normal') {
    for (let question of section.question_list) {
      if (question.qtype == 'input-text') {
        const control: FormControl = new FormControl(question.answer, Validators.required);
        section.form.addControl(question.key, control);
      }
      if (question.qtype == 'input-email') {
        const control: FormControl = new FormControl(question.answer, Validators.email);
        section.form.addControl(question.key, control);
      }
      if (question.qtype == 'multi-choice') {
        for (let choice of question.qchoices) {
          const control: FormControl = new FormControl(choice.selected, Validators.required);
          section.form.addControl(choice.key, control);
        }
      }
      else {
        const control: FormControl = new FormControl(question.answer, Validators.required);
        section.form.addControl(question.key, control);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share how you create your form controls ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun , I've added the code. I don't think that there's a problem in it, since it works perfectly fine if I trigger some manual action after init

Comment: While doing `new FormControl(question.answer, Validators.required)`, you specify a default value as `question.answer`. This value is not the right one for some controls ?

Comment: There is always question.answer, if the answer doesnt exist, it just an empty string “”. In other words, new FormControl(“”,Validators.required)

Comment: In the `ngOnInit` you create your each control with a default value then you want to change this value by another. Why don't you just put the right value while creating the form ?

Comment: Have you tried to do update your controls in **ngAfterViewInit** ?

Comment: @SebastienServouze Thanks a lot, I don't know how I didn't remember to try it. How ever, I also had to use ChangeDetectorRef to prevent ExpressionChangedError. Feel free to add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update controls in **ngAfterViewInit**.

This is because **ngOnInit** is called before the view is fully initialized.

More infos here : [Angular Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)